ROS2 ur driver: package failed: ur_controllers
I am trying to install universal robot driver in ROS2 Humble, following this guide:
https://docs.ros.org/en/ros2_packages/rolling/api/ur_robot_driver/installation/installation.html
In the colcon step I get this error
colcon build --cmake-args -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
Starting >>> ur_dashboard_msgs
Starting >>> ur_moveit_config
Finished <<< ur_moveit_config [0.27s]                                                                  
Finished <<< ur_dashboard_msgs [0.60s]                     
Starting >>> ur_controllers
--- stderr: ur_controllers                             
/home/pedro/workspace/ros_ur_driver/src/Universal_Robots_ROS2_Driver/ur_controllers/src/scaled_joint_trajectory_controller.cpp: In member function ‘virtual controller_interface::return_type ur_controllers::ScaledJointTrajectoryController::update(const rclcpp::Time&, const rclcpp::Duration&)’:
/home/pedro/workspace/ros_ur_driver/src/Universal_Robots_ROS2_Driver/ur_controllers/src/scaled_joint_trajectory_controller.cpp:319:16: error: no matching function for call to ‘ur_controllers::ScaledJointTrajectoryController::publish_state(const rclcpp::Time&, trajectory_msgs::msg::JointTrajectoryPoint&, trajectory_msgs::msg::JointTrajectoryPoint&, trajectory_msgs::msg::JointTrajectoryPoint&)’
  319 |   publish_state(time, state_desired_, state_current_, state_error_);
      |   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/pedro/workspace/ros_ur_driver/src/Universal_Robots_ROS2_Driver/ur_controllers/include/ur_controllers/scaled_joint_trajectory_controller.hpp:41,
                 from /home/pedro/workspace/ros_ur_driver/src/Universal_Robots_ROS2_Driver/ur_controllers/src/scaled_joint_trajectory_controller.cpp:41:
/opt/ros/humble/include/joint_trajectory_controller/joint_trajectory_controller/joint_trajectory_controller.hpp:260:8: note: candidate: ‘void joint_trajectory_controller::JointTrajectoryController::publish_state(const JointTrajectoryPoint&, const JointTrajectoryPoint&, const JointTrajectoryPoint&)’
  260 |   void publish_state(
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/humble/include/joint_trajectory_controller/joint_trajectory_controller/joint_trajectory_controller.hpp:260:8: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 4 provided
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ur_controllers.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/ur_controllers.dir/src/scaled_joint_trajectory_controller.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:223: CMakeFiles/ur_controllers.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:146: all] Error 2
---
Failed   <<< ur_controllers [1.87s, exited with code 2]

Summary: 2 packages finished [2.62s]
  1 package failed: ur_controllers
  1 package had stderr output: ur_controllers
  3 packages not processed

I have no idea what else I need to install.
Can you help me?
thank you

Welcome at RSE.
Why don't you install the released package but want to build it from source?
It seems that you have to checkout the humble branch of the ur_robot_driver. The API changed in the upstream ros2_controllers repo.
